# Make regex match past line end

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build a regex to help me parse lots of robots.txt files.  I am trying to find if specific user-agents have been disallowed.

Files look roughly like his but can vary a bit with whitepace:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /next/

User-agent: *
Disallow: /mshots/v1/

# har har
User-agent: *
Disallow: /activate/

User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-login.php

User-agent: *
Disallow: /signup/

User-agent: *
Disallow: /related-tags.php
```

So far I have come up with this regex:

```
user-agent.*:(.*$)
```

With options set for multiline and ignorecase.

This works great for the user-agent part of my requirement but now I need to match any `dissallow` word that comes before another `user-agent` is declared.  I have tried matching `$` and `\r\n` but I can't figure out how to keep the match going after the `$`.  Any pattern I add after doesn't seem to work. For instance:

```
user-agent.*:(.*$)(^.*disallow)
```

I am trying to match the newline and then dissallow but it doesn't match.  Also I am not sure how to terminate the match before the `user-agent` and still work on last declaard rule.

Can anyone point me in right direction?

Comment: Not sure what you are after, but see [the `user-agent.*:(.*)(\n.*disallow)` regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=user-agent.*%3a%28.*%29%28%5cn.*disallow%29&i=User-agent%3a+*%0d%0aDisallow%3a+%2fnext%2f%0d%0a%0d%0aUser-agent%3a+*%0d%0aDisallow%3a+%2fmshots%2fv1%2f&o=i). Just `$` does not match a line break, it only matches a position before `\n`.

Comment: In Javascript the regex would require `/gmi` at the end for multiple. multiline and case insensitive match. Not quite sure about c#. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/7AcZh8/1/)

Comment: Ahh thanks, I was trying one or the other.  Sometimes there is empty lines between user-agent and disallow.  I had a play with your demo but couldn't figure that out, is there a symbol that matches any character and any end of line?

Comment: @NisargShah in C# its passed in as an enum

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think it might just be issue with tester, I tried same regex in javascript one and it worked, I'll try out in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)user-agent.*:(.*)([\r\n]\s*.*disallow)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=user-agent.*%3A%28.*%29%28%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%5Cs*.*disallow%29&i=User-agent%3A%20*%0D%0ADisallow%3A%20%2Fnext%2F%0D%0A%0D%0AUser-agent%3A%20*%0D%0ADisallow%3A%20%2Fmshots%2Fv1%2F&o=i). You do not need a `RegexOptions.Multiline` option here, because there is no need using `^`, nor `$` that would need redefining their behavior of.

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `user-agent` - a literal substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than a newline, as many as possible
- `:` - a colon
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than a newline up to the end of the line
- `([\r\n]\s*.*disallow)` - Group 2:

  - `[\r\n]\s*` - a line break char (CR or LF) and then 0+ whitespaces
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than a newline, as many as possible
  - `disallow` - a substring

Comment: `user-agent.*:(.*)([\r?\n]\s*.*disallow)` will work with linux line endings as well?

Comment: @Guerrilla Remove `?` from `[\r?\n]`. The `[\r?\n]` pattern matches a CR, `?` or LF. Just `[\r\n]\s*` is enough. Any linebreak starts with either `\r` or `\n`, so `[\r\n]` will match the starting part of it (in Windows, CRLF is the line break), or the whole line break (in Unix/Linux, LF, in MacOS early versions, CR) and `\s*` will match the rest of the whitespaces there are left.

Comment: ahh because its matching `\r` or `\n` i get it now.  Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be that your are not matching the newline between the `User-agent: *` and `Disallow`.

A regex like this should work: `/^user-agent: (.*)$[\s]^disallow: (.*)$/igm`

This regex will capture the value of `User-agent` and the value of `Disallow`, and will work with any type of newline.
The `igm` flags mean case-**I**nsensitive, **G**lobal and **M**ultiline

You can test it using [regexr](https://regexr.com/3gst8).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SingleLine` option and the following regular expression:

```
    String pattern = @"user-agent[^\r\n]*: ([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]+disallow[^\r\n]*: ([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]+";

    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(robots, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline))
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("---------");
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Match: `" + match.ToString() + "`");
        foreach (Group grp in match.Groups)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("    Group: ``" + grp.ToString() + "``");
        }               
    }
```

Breaking down the pattern:

A literal `user-agent` followed by any number of non-CRLF characters followed gy a colon and then a space.
`user-agent[^\r\n]*:`

At least one non-CRLF character as a group.
`([^\r\n]+)`

At least one CRLF character.
`[\r\n]+`

A literal `disallow` followed by any number of non-CRLF characters followed gy a colon and then a space.
`disallow[^\r\n]*:`

At least non-CRLF characters as a group.
`([^\r\n]+)`

At least one CRLF character.
[\r\n]+

The `SingleLine` option means "treat the input as a single line."